# Make [install] a synonym of [installation]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are already two synonyms for [installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation): [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installing) and [setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setup). So [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/install) would fit, too.

Comment: Smells meta to me.  Burninate.

Comment: In Ask Ubuntu we removed this tag in favor of [software-installation]. In Unix and Linux we just banned it. StackOverflow is a programming oriented site, not a user oriented one, yet two user oriented sites removed a tag about a user/administrator task.

Answer (score 5):

This is now done:

[installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation) ← [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/install)

[installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation) ← [installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installer)

[installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation) ← [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installing)

[installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation) ← [setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setup)

And some more:

[uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstallation) ← [uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstall)

[uninstallation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstallation) ← [uninstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uninstaller)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the tag pages for [install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/install), [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installing) and [installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation) suggests they should be the same tag:

[installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installation) (synonym - [installing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/installing)):

> The process of installation is the deployment of an application onto a device for future execution and use.

[install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/install):

> Installation (or setup) of a program (including drivers, plugins, etc.) is the act of putting the program onto a computer system so that it can be executed.

It's high time this happened.